# Messagefile parameter SQL Server 2000 / 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

SQL experts,

I was using the messagefile parameter of SQL Server 2000 `xp_smtp_sendmail` procedure to use external text files as bodies of my mails. We migrated recently to SQL Server 2005 and this parameter is not present in `sp_send_dbmail`.

Is there a simple way to do the same in SQL Server 2005.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

No there is no message file in `sp_send_dbmail`.

I´ve been reading some articles about the subject and I you have some option for you. Getting the file with a [CLR function to Read and Write Text Files](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2341/use-the-sql-server-clr-to-read-and-write-text-files/) and then put the return into the body of the mail. Then something like this:

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX)
EXEC @text=ReadTextFile 'C:\YourFile.txt'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'something',
@recipients = 'someuser@somemail.com',
@body = @text,
@subject = 'Hello my friend' ;
```

Or you can use the `OPENROWSET` and load the file in a varchar (more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)):

```
DECLARE @LotsOfText VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @LotsOfText = BulkColumn
FROM    OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\YourFile.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'something',
@recipients = 'someuser@somemail.com',
@body = @LotsOfText,
@subject = 'Hello my friend' ;
```

[The TSQL of Text Files](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-tsql-of-text-files/) is a good reference for reading file in sql.

I hope this will help

Comment: Arion, I used the OPENROWSET alternative and I can say it works smoothly. I was even able to import 'htm' files by replacing the SINGLE_BLOB by SINGLE_CLOB. My email bodies are now loaded with what exactly I wanted. Great ... and thanks again !

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.. Maybe you can accept the answer then?.. and remember to upvote the answer you think are good. That gives us all a warm fuzzy feeling :P